# Is there a "template engine" in Python to generate SQL?

Tags: sql, python-2.7, sqlite

How do I generate SQL code for a SQLite3 database somehow dynamically with something like a template engine? I'm new to this and I'm using jinja2 to generate HTML. Could jinja2 possibly be used for such a purpose as well, if so, is that a good idea? I would like my program to save all the data (attribute values of instances of various classes) before it stops running.

Comment: You're looking for ORMs - Object Relational Mappers. SO isn't the place for software recommendations however.

Comment: Also it doesn't really sound like you want a database; surely serializing to JSON or another format (ex. using Python's `json` module) would be easier?

Answer (score 3):

check out https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jinjasql/0.1.6
it seems to basically just apply jinja2 to SQL templates. I haven't played with it much yet but was just asking the same question and came upon this.

Comment: Note there is a very dangerous infinite loop bug in this library: https://github.com/hashedin/jinjasql/pull/17

Comment: For posterity, the infinite loop bug has been resolved, thanks @BenRudolph!